# Правильное хранение лайков/дислайков (голосования) в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, хранение-данных

Есть сайт, на котором должна быть организована система голосования (лайк/дислайк). Если записывать в БД информацию в виде `номер_записи` - `id_пользователя`, то вроде бы всё хорошо. Но. Возьмем 100 записей и 100 пользователей. Каждый из них проголосует за каждую запись, в итоге в БД будет содержаться 10.000 записей, а это проблема.
Почитав немного, изменил таблицу и она стала вида:
`номер_записи` - `id_всех_пользователей_которые_голосовали`.
 При тех же условиях вместо 10.000 получим всего 100 записей в БД.

Добавление нового `id` пользователя происходит так:

1. забираем всю строку из БД, где номер записи равен N
2. `SELECT FROM WHERE users_id LIKE '%id_пользователя%'` - запрос,
   чтобы проверить существование уже этого `id` в строке
3. в случае успешной проверки добавляем в конец строки новый `id` и
   заносим в БД новую строку.

Насколько это правильный подход к хранению такого рода информации? Какие есть альтернативы? Готов услышать и принять к сведению.

Comment: Если у вас у пользователя `id = 2`  а в строке занесены идентификаторы `22,32,42` то запрос `SELECT FROM WHERE users_id LIKE '%id_пользователя%'` выдаст результат..хотя на самом деле его там нет....А что вы будете делать когда у вас кончится размер строки с идентификаторами?

Comment: А почему 100К записей это проблема? Записи-то все integer type, так что для базы не составит труда ими оперировать... Единственное что, для ускорения работы я бы хранил кол-во проголосовавших за и против в таблице записей. Две доп. integer поля погоды не сделают, а получение общих данных ускоряет...

Comment: `номер_записи` - `id_пользователя`
Стандартная система, так логичнее и правильнее. Я бы на вашем месте ничего не мудрил.
Ведь ещё ключик будет вида UNIQUE KEY(`номер_записи`, `id_пользователя`), запросы по индексу. Если не супернагруженная система (уверен на 99% что это так), то не стоит усложнять.

Comment: `номер_записи - id_пользователя` - типичный стандартный вариант. Почему вы это нашли плохим вариантом? ведь добавить индексы к столбцам и всё будет быстро и хорошо. А так вам придется парсить строки и склеивать обратно при `insert` много лишних операций.

Comment: Спасибо, что сказали про LIKE, тк думал, что он работает несколько иначе. Подумал, что плохой вариант из-за большого количества записей в БД при маленьком количестве новостей на сайте. Но пошёл исправляться)

Comment: @FLighter Просто добавлю.....большое количество записей, это если бы номер `id` таблицы достиг бы максимума значения integer для `mysql`.... а оно равно `BIGINT = 9223372036854775807` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html ... так что беспокоиться о 10.000 записей не стоит. это капля в море....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прикинем, как часто что требуется.

1. **сумма** (или две суммы: за и против) по конкретному голосованию – *супер-часто* – при каждом открытии страницы с этим голосованием.
2. **голосовал ли** данный юзер за данный опрос? – *реже*, при приёме нового голоса.
3. **кто проголосовал** за / против за данный вопрос? – *ещё реже*, если вообще это открытая инфа.
4. **как и где голосовал** данный юзер – тоже, вероятно, *совсем редко*, если вообще.

Итого, текущие суммы храним в каком-нибудь быстром кэше, типа memcached/apc/redis.

При поступлении нового голоса в БД надо проверить, голосовал ли? и сохранить голос + обновить кэшированную сумму. Хорошо иметь отдельную таблицу только для голосов:

```
id_опроса   id_юзера   голос_плюс_минус (1 бит)
```

Основной индекс составной - по обоим id - т.к. будем искать и по вопросу-юзеру (можно ли принять голос - может быть только одна запись с парой `qid,uid`) и по опросу (кто-как). И ещё индекс только по юзеру (где голосовал).

Да, будет запись в БД и двух индексах на каждый отданный голос. Хоть 10 млн. – это нормально. Каждая запись – два 32-битных целых и 1 бит. Когда проект вырастет – станете горизонтально масштабировать – скажем, id опросов меньше X уедут на доп. MySQL сервер.

Comment: Спасибо. По факту тогда остается таблица с записями, где также добавлены столбцы "количество голосов за", "количество голосов против", "общий рейтинг" и отдельная таблица для голосов, где два id и tinyint(1), чтобы понять: "за" или "против". По мере нарастания делается ограничение и остальные данные уходят на другой сервер и так до бесконечности.
Поправьте, если не так понял.

Comment: Всё верно. С уточнением: незачем держать «общий рейтинг», который вычисляется вычитанием двух других полей.